# Nested Query on mongodb not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Structure of Document:

[image]

Mongoose Schema:

```
var mongoSchema = new Schema({
name:  String,
description: String,
location: { lat: Number, long: Number },
images: [String],
blocks: { text: String, logo: String },
subLocations: {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    location: {
         lat: Number,
         long: Number
    },
    images: [String]
    }
});
```

Following Query does not work:

```
mongooseModel.find().
   where('location.lat').equals(18.710145).
   exec(function(err, response) {
}
```

While this query does work:

```
mongooseModel.find().
   where('lat').equals("18.710145").
   exec(function(err, response) {
}
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

the datatype of the nested lat (location.lat) is a String (look at your embedded image, far right column). that's why your first query didn't work -- you're comparing a Number to a String.

Comment: But I verified that it is casted as a number due to the mongoose defined schema. Also even after converting it to "18.710145" the query does not return any results.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query to find out your result.

```
db.myCollection.find( { $where: {"location":{"lat":"18.710145"}} } );
```

Comment: This isnt using mongoose, its via the MongoDbClient right?